# Macro sequentially to prepend three characters

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to add the text "PPL" to a pre generated list of coupon codes to upload to my website, our vendor's system only generates 10 digit codes and my website only accepts 13 digit codes.

How should I write the VB macro to simply add those three letters to each of the cell's contents?

Comment: You don't want to add an adjoining column with `="PPD"&A1`?

Comment: Why do you need a macro? Sounds like an easy case for spreadsheet formulas. If you pre-generated list is in column A, starting at A1, in B1 enter the formula `= "PPL" & A1` and copy down.

Answer (score 0):

Consider just adding an adjoining column, the first cell containing `="PPD"&A1` and fill the column down.

Otherwise, this is a simple for loop.

```
Dim cel as Range

For Each cel in ThisWorksheet.UsedRage
  if Len(cel) = 10 then cel = "PPD" & cel
Next
```